# How to acces the data of root folder(/) of an android device?

Tags: android, filesystems

I'm storing the DB file to the path `/data/data/somefolder/` in my application. I want to get the file from this folder in my system or in my device so that I can view the content in it. I'm able to pull the file from emulator, but I'm not able to get the file from device. Is there any app which can do this?

PS: Programatically I'm able to access the file

Comment: I don't think its is possible to view internal data of application. If you saved data in external memory then you can view it.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see that [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) to get the "/data/data/somefolder/" directory with `getExternalStorageDirectory()` method

While inserting and retrieving you path you have to store fullpath to get solve out your problem.

**EDITED :** AFAIK its not possible to access internal data but you can create your same folder in external directory for future Use and access it when you required.

If you want to Access it from device then you can also create Folder at path `"sdcard/YOUR_APPLICATION/XYZ/"` location with Full path location in database.

Comment: I want to copy the physical file from this location, I dont want to do this programmatically.

Comment: @Jai: AFAIK its not possible to access internal data but you can create your same folder in external directory for future Use and access it when you required.

Answer (score 2):

You can store file in internal storage so there is need to specify path from root. simply you can write/ create file like: File f= new File("myfile.txt");

and use it as you want. and it will not visible to other apps so its most secure.

If you still want to store on external storage like micro SDCard or phones built in storage then please try following:

File root = new File("/");
get all the folders from root

String[] folders = root.list();

and use one of them as you want.

or 
Use above mentioned methods like getExternalStorageDirectory().......

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, when the device is rooted. If not you can still get the file when your app is built in debug mode. Try on your development machine

```
adb shell
```

and then on the device

```
run-as your.package.name
cd databases
cat your.db.file > /sdcard/your.db.file
```

and then you can copy it from your sd card.